# Why has my LUKS volume started showing that it has an unexpected second partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, btrfs, luks

I have 3 disks:

- /dev/sdb is a 2TB HDD
- /dev/sdc is a 1TB HDD
- /dev/sdd is a 1TB HDD

I used cryptsetup to format these 3 drives with LUKS. I then created a BTRFS raid1 volume using the 3 devices.

As expected, the output of lsblk after this was:

```
sdb
- int2tb ... 1.8T crypt /mnt/Storage
sdc
- int1tb ... 931.5G crypt
sdd
- int1tb ... 931.5G crypt
```

I added some files to the mounted BTRFS volume and then came back a few days later. Nothing was done with any of the disks other than this, but now lsblk shows the following:

```
sdc
- sdc2 ... 547.3G part
- int1tb ... 931.5G crypt
```

This sdc2 partition has appeared for no apparent reason. Running `file -s /dev/sdc` shows the data about it being a LUKS volume as expected. But running `file -s /dev/sdc2` just gives the output `data`, or `file /dev/sdc2` gives `block special (8/34)`. Running BTRFS commands such as `btrfs fi show` shows the 3 disks with details as expected.

What might be the cause of this partition appearing? Is it problematic or can it be ignored? Is there anything further I can do to investigate this partition and possibly fix the issue without wiping the drive?

Comment: When, on a whole device (like `sdc`), you create any structure other than a proper partition table, you are risking that "random" data where a partition table usually is will by chance resemble a partition table. *Maybe* this is what happened. What is the output of `file -skr /dev/sdc`?

Comment: The output of that command is `/dev/sdc: LUKS encrypted file, ver 2...` and then just `- data` on the next line. I figured that might be the case though wasn't sure if it was really possible, but it is looking like the reason, especially since the partition seemed to appear only after writing data. Thanks